# On submit change http params and make the request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm doing a car selling website and I need to remove some spaces and special characters from some params, when the user submits the form, otherwise this happens:

[image]

I know how to do this, but the problem is when I update these params, the request is made without them...

[image]

Here is my code (I'm using Select2.js for the selects):

```
<%= form_tag filter_vehicles_path, method: 'get', onsubmit: 'editFields()'  do %>
    <h4><strong>

      <span>Fabricante</span>
      <%= collection_select :manufacturer, :manufacturer_id, Manufacturer.joins(:vehicles).uniq, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "manufacturer_dropdown"} %>

      <span>Modelo</span>
      <%= grouped_collection_select :model, :model_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :models, :name,  :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "model_dropdown", data: {models: @models}} %>

      <span>Preço</span>
      <%= select_tag :price_start, options_for_select([ "250 €", "500 €", "1000 €", "2 000 €", "3 000 €", "4 000 €", "5 000 €", "6 000 €", "7 000 €", "8 000 €", "9 000 €", "10 000 €", "12 000 €", "14 000 €", "16 000 €", "18 000 €", "20 000 €", "22 000 €", "24 000 €", "26 000 €", "28 000 €", "30 000 €", "32 000 €", "34 000 €", "36 000 €", "38 000 €", "40 000 €", "50 000 €", "60 000 €", "70 000 €", "80 000 €", "90 000 €", "100 000 €", "150 000 €", "200 000 €"]), include_blank: true, class:"select2PriceFrom" %>
      <%= select_tag :price_ending, options_for_select([ "250 €", "500 €", "1000 €", "2 000 €", "3 000 €", "4 000 €", "5 000 €", "6 000 €", "7 000 €", "8 000 €", "9 000 €", "10 000 €", "12 000 €", "14 000 €", "16 000 €", "18 000 €", "20 000 €", "22 000 €", "24 000 €", "26 000 €", "28 000 €", "30 000 €", "32 000 €", "34 000 €", "36 000 €", "38 000 €", "40 000 €", "50 000 €", "60 000 €", "70 000 €", "80 000 €", "90 000 €", "100 000 €", "150 000 €", "200 000 €"]), include_blank: true, class:"select2PriceTo" %>

      <span>Ano</span>
      <%= select_tag :year_start, options_for_select((1990..Date.today.year).to_a.reverse + ["1980", "1970", "1960", "1950", "1940", "1930", "1920", "1910", "1900"]), {include_blank: true, maxlength: 4, class:"select2YearFrom validateSize"} %>
      <%= select_tag :year_start, options_for_select((1990..Date.today.year).to_a.reverse + ["1980", "1970", "1960", "1950", "1940", "1930", "1920", "1910", "1900"]), {include_blank: true, maxlength: 4, class:"select2YearTo validateSize"} %>

      <span>Quilómetros</span>
      <%= select_tag :kms_start, options_for_select([ "5 000 km", "10 000 km", "15 000 km", "20 000 km", "25 000 km", "30 000 km", "35 000 km", "50 000 km", "75 000 km", "100 000 km", "125 000 km", "150 000 km", "200 000 km", "250 000 km", "300 000 km", "350 000 km", "400 000 km", "450 000 km", "500 000 km"]), include_blank: true, class:"select2From" %>
      <%= select_tag :kms_end, options_for_select([ "5 000 km", "10 000 km", "15 000 km", "20 000 km", "25 000 km", "30 000 km", "35 000 km", "50 000 km", "75 000 km", "100 000 km", "125 000 km", "150 000 km", "200 000 km", "250 000 km", "300 000 km", "350 000 km", "400 000 km", "450 000 km", "500 000 km"]), include_blank: true, class:"select2To" %>

      <%= submit_tag "Pesquisar" %>
    </strong></h4>
  <% end %>
```

My js file:

```
function editFields(){
   $("#price_start").val($("#price_start").val().replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/\€/g, ""));
}
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use pushstate that javascript provides to change the url as you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: So you have a select with `<option value="250 €">` or `<option>250 €</option>`and you try to set it to `250`  - that will likely set it to null. Instead use a VALUE of 250 and a TEXT of 250 € OR remove the space and the € on the server

Comment: @mplungjan I have those options for the user, but he can input his own value. If for exemple he puts `3450` the application will put automatically `3 450 €` for a better UX. But when the user submits, I want to remove that spaces and symbol. 

Why changing that will set it to null? Thanks :)

Comment: I assume `<%= select_tag :price_start` creates a `<select id="price_start">` Right? If so, when you set the value of it, it tries to change to the option that has the value: `$("#price_start").val(someValue)` - if someValue does not exist in the select, you basically set the value to null or similar - it is an antipattern to try to "fix" the user's input on the client only

Comment: Ohhh ok... It makes sense. But if the value is null or similar as you said, he should still appear on the url like the others (even if he is null like the others) or I'm mistaken?

Comment: @AlbertoCh I think that is not quite what I want. I just need to edit that param before the request is made, or is not possible what I want? Thank you :)

Comment: @Proz1g would be much better you could filter param at controller side?

Comment: @Gabbar it is an option, but I would prefer to do it before. The url would look cleaner :)